# OutlineSpotShadowColor under API 28

Tags: kotlin, shadow, android-chips

I'm trying to disable clicking effect on Material Chip. In Api>28 there is outlineSpotShadowColor attribute. And how to handle this on Api<28?

In my adapter i'm adding chip and disabling this color:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    chip.outlineSpotShadowColor = binding.root.context.resources.getColor(transparent)
  } else { What should i do here?}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API less the 28 can try the `outlineProvider` of the `chip` to `null` this will disable the clicking effect.

In the else block just add: `chip.outlineProvider = null`